# Explorer.exe making outbound TCP connection to Akamai

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, malware

I've just noticed that my c:\windows\explorer.exe executable has attempted to make an outbound connection from localhost:49844 -> 104.111.87.125:443.

It seems that this IP is registered to Akamai, but I never know how to be sure whether or not things like this are malware related. I've done some research and it seems that others have encountered situations similar to mine, but none with the specific IP.

Can anyone shed some light on exactly what this is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akamai is a legitimate Content Provider company proving content out to users on the web. That is a legitimate connection and not to worry.

https://www.akamai.com/

104.111.87.125:443 via Smart Whois

> 104.111.87.125
>
> 104.64.0.0 - 104.127.255.255
>
> Akamai Technologies, Inc. 145 Broadway Cambridge MA 02142 United
> States
>
> Yeung, Kam Sze
> +852-92813828 ip-admin@akamai.com Schecter, Steven Jay
> +1-617-274-7134 ip-admin@akamai.com ipadmin
> +1-617-444-0017 ip-admin@akamai.com
>
> NOC United States
> +1-617-444-2535 abuse@akamai.com
>
> AKAMAI Created: 1999-01-21 Updated: 2020-08-26 Source: whois.arin.net
>
> Completed at 10/27/2020 6:38:35 PM Processing time: 0.47 seconds View
> source

Comment: I figured this would be the answer, but I wasn't sure. I suppose there's no real way that any Akamai connection would ever be malware related, unless Akamai themselves were attacked?

Comment: I have not got any malware from Akamai - so again - no worries.  Hopefully then you will acknowledge my answer.

Comment: But impossible and improbable are two different things. It sounds more like you're saying it's unlikely to be malware, but is there a way to be 100% certain?

Comment: Sites like Akamai and others are very well secured and protected. I am not saying “impossible “ but I do think it to be highly improbable. Lots of Companies use Akamai.